# Enable remote management remotely on a mac

Tags: bash, ssh, script, administrator, apple-remote-desktop

I am trying to use remote desktop to send a script to all Macs on my network that creates an *additional* admin account and hides it. I am trying to do this using Apple Remote Desktop. However most of these macs have remote management disabled.

How do I do I turn this on? Each Mac already has an admin account. Does that help? Can I do this through remote login (ssh)? But most of these macs also have that disabled. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Think about what you're asking - to be able to remote into another machine without admin permission, in order to add new functionality & admin accounts. Any OS that would allow that wouldn't be one I'd be using.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for your reply...we do have an admin account on there so if I were to go to everyone's computer I could do the whole process manually without needing to get into their account. But of course I'd like a better way than to go to everyone's computer to enable a feature. What do you think would be the best course of action?

Comment: I thought that was the whole purpose of having OS X Server installed on a machine.

Comment: @bret7600 are you saying that I should have OS X Server set up and somehow have ARD setup and through the Server never let them turn it off, or? something else?

Comment: @youngandcrazy that's what i think, Yes.

Comment: @bret7600 any documentation on that? Even though that doesn't help for right now it might help for future management of Macs.

Comment: @youngandcrazy here is the advanced administration section of the OS X server docs. http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/4.0/ and the normal server docs https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/4.0/

Answer (score 2):

1. ssh adminusername@ip_address
2. sudo
   /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate

Comment: not sure why this was -1'd, but it might help, I haven't tried yet. I guess it would require manual GUI use? I found that remote management doesn't seem to be able to rely on groups, unlike remote login, which can use group=Administrators. I want to make sure a new admin user can also remotely manage.

Comment: Warning: macos 10.14 and later only allows control if Screen Sharing is enabled through System Preferences.